# Why Mongoose validation isn't working in Keystone.js app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, keystonejs

Is there validation on required fields, email field and name field in Keystone.js?

Here is my User model for example:

```
const keystone = require('keystone');
const Types = keystone.Field.Types;
const User = new keystone.List('User');

User.add({
  name: { type: Types.Name, required: true, initial: true, index: true },
  email: { type: Types.Email, required: true, initial: true, index: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: Types.Password, initial: true, required: true },
}, 'Permissions', {
  isAdmin: { type: Boolean, label: 'Can access Keystone', index: true },
});

// Provide access to Keystone
User.schema.virtual('canAccessKeystone').get(function () {
  return this.isAdmin;
});

User.defaultColumns = 'name, email, isAdmin';
User.register();
```

And some sort of unit tests. The last two fail because error isn't throwing.

```
const User = keystone.list('User').model;

describe('User model', function () {
  const newUser = {
    name: {
      first: 'Test',
      last: 'Testov',
    },
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: 'test',
  };

  describe('validation', function () {
    it('should reject a new user without email', function (done) {
      const invalidUser = Object.assign({}, newUser);
      delete invalidUser.email;
      new User(invalidUser).validate((err) => {
        assert.equal('Path `email` is required.', err.errors.email.message);
        done();
      });
    });

    it('should reject a new user without password', function (done) {
      const invalidUser = Object.assign({}, newUser);
      delete invalidUser.password;
      new User(invalidUser).validate((err) => {
        assert.equal('Path `password` is required.', err.errors.password.message);
        done();
      });
    });

    it('should reject a new user with invalid email', function (done) {
      const invalidUser = Object.assign({}, newUser);
      invalidUser.email = 'roflrofl';
      new User(invalidUser).validate((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        assert.isOk(err);
        done();
      });
    });

    it('should reject a new user without name', function (done) {
      const invalidUser = Object.assign({}, newUser);
      invalidUser.name = { omg: 'wtf' };
      new User(invalidUser).validate((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        assert.isOk(err);
        done();
       });
    });
  });
});
```

So the first two unit tests is passing positive but the last two not. Why the validation isn't work?

Comment: which Keystone version?

Comment: @Creynders 4.0.0- beta5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `validate` method isn't a keystone method, but one that mongoose provides. And mongoose has far more limited validation than keystone. 
The `required: true` options are passed to the mongoose schema, which is why it throws when you're trying to leave a required field blank. 
There's no real keystone equivalent for `validate`, but the (mongoose+keystone) validation will run whenever you try to save a document.

P.s. realised too late that it had nothing to do with the Keystone version

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I've just found out, that there is no method of validation email field, so it isn't obvious why I assume to use keystone email type instead String. For completing your answer I just want to add, that it's possible to define validation method for email field in mongoose model

Comment: @VadimShvetsov Keystone _does_ do some additional validation for email fields, but only when you save them. This is run automatically if you save them in the admin UI. However if you're working with documents directly you'll need to use List.updateItem (v4) or the updateHandler (v0.3) to benefit from the additional validation

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is a definitely full answer!

Comment: By the way I've realized that keystone type Name isn't validate required field because it's props first and last isn't required in name type definition.